# Actionscript 3.0 Rotating an Image, by 90 degrees, that was loaded from a url

Tags: actionscript-3, image, rotation, degrees

I got an error saying **"Attempted access of inaccessible method rotation through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.ssd.rotation(90)}"**
I just want to know how to rotate my image by 90degrees when I double click on it.

```
var shootingstar:Loader = new Loader();
shootingstar.load(new URLRequest("http://i51.tinypic.com/m8jp7m.png"));
shootingstar.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadingComplete);
var ssd:Sprite = new Sprite();
 function onLoadingComplete(event:Event):void
 {
    ssd.addChild( event.currentTarget.loader.content );
    ssd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    ssd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
    ssd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, rotate)
 ssd.height=180
 ssd.width=124
 }
 function drag(event:MouseEvent):void{
     ssd.startDrag()
  }
 function drop(event:MouseEvent):void{
  ssd.stopDrag()
 }
 function rotate():void{
     ssd.rotation(90)
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests that the rotation method is not accessible , i.e , private or protected. Therefore you're not able to call it directly as in your code rotation(90).

Instead you should be using the rotation public property

```
    rotation = 90;
```

As superfro points out, you should also get an error from the rotate method which requires a MouseEvent parameter. So practically..

```
function rotate(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   ssd.rotation = 90;
}
```

Finally, makes sure that the doubleClickEnabled property of the Sprite is set to true

```
function onLoadingComplete(event:Event):void
{
   ssd.doubleClickEnabled = true;
   etc....
```

Comment: sd.doubleClickEnabled = true;
I needed the doubleclick enabled

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ssd.rotation = 90;` ?

Comment: Yeah but it didn't work. I saw a post somewhere that they used parenthesis

Comment: ssd.rotation = 90 should be correct.  Check the doc http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#rotation

Comment: your rotate() function should be defined as rotate(event:MouseEvent):void like the other mouse event handlers, add a trace("test") inside your function, and see if you see the output when you double click.  Maybe your function isn't being called at all ?